# Reminder for Tasks in Gmail's Tasks list (Google)

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, google-tasks

Is it possible to assign a reminder to a task entry in the tasks list of my Gmail? I can see the tasks in the calendar, but I did not find how to add a reminder...

Comment: Although you can set a "due date", unfortunately I don't think Google itself allows you to set a reminder. However, some 3rd party apps/tools that read your Google Tasks do. For instance, I use [Tasks on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.teamtasks.tasks) which connects directly with your Google Tasks and this app does remind you when tasks are due. It also allows you to set a time, which Google does not (only the date is sync'd with Google).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short script I wrote that copies tasks with due dates to the calendar (which you can set to have reminders for)
http://msftb.blogspot.com/2015/09/why-cant-you-get-calendar-alerts-from.html